# Do individual List permissions override Site / User permissions?

Tags: list, permissions, item

I have a basic SharePoint (2013, I think) site (I am a SharePoint novice...) with a List, to which a large number of users have access.
All Users need to be able to:
- View all Items
- Add a new Item

A workflow automatically launches upon Item creation which generates a unique Item 'Reference' (based on the Item ID) and adds this to a 'Ref.' column after Item creation.

Therefore, all Users have been given custom permissions to View, Add and Edit Items in the List.

However, I would like to restrict their access to only be able to Edit Items which THEY have created themselves (not other users' Items).

How can I do this?  At the moment, the Users' permissions which allow them to Edit list Items seems to override the List level setting which says 'Edit Items created by the User'.

Answer (score 2):

In Advanced Settings of a Custom List you will have the option to set Item-Level Permissions, if you have a Library this option will not be available.[image]

Comment: Thanks.  I have selected this option, however the users still have the ability to Edit all items, including those they did not create.  The Group permissions seem to override this List / Item level permission.  I  need to know if there is a way around this?  They need to have Edit access so that the workflow will progress as it has to manipulate a value in the item after saving.